# Facebook social plugins: Change url and share/like data

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am doing some maintenance which include url changes. I want to keep the share/like count from `data-href="mysite.com/oldUrl"` and use it on `data-href="mysite.com/newUrl"`

I tried using `data-href="mysite.com/oldUrl"` on the new url, problem with that is when someone on facebook clicks the link it still goes the old url... Not suprised though, but it was worth a shot!

The site is pure html, so I cant use wordpress plugins.

Suggestions highly appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

Try to use .htacess to make a 301 redir of the old url for the new one like this:

RedirectMatch 301 ^/oldname/ http://www.sample.com/newname/